# How is this not a polyhedron?

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry, matrix-equations, polyhedra, convex-hulls

I am faced with this problem:

$P=\{x\in R^n| x\ge 0, x^Ty\le 1$for all $y$ with $||y||_2=1\}$

Is $P$ a polyhedron?

I said yes, for the following reasoning:

Since the definition of a polyhedron is $P=\{x\in R^n|A^Tx\le b, Fx=g\}$, I can put it into that form above like this:

- First of all, by squaring both sides of $||y||_2=1$ we can get $||y||_2^2=1$ so that $\Sigma y_i^2=1$
- Then I can form matrices for all of the restrictions like so:

$A=[diag(-1);y^T]$
(this is the concatenation of a diagonal matrix of -1's and then the vector $y$ on the bottom.  Multiplying this with the $x$ vector seems to satisfy the inequality from what i can tel $Ax \le b$

And for the equality constraint we can write $y^Ty=1$

This seems to make it a polyhedron...but apparently the TA says that this is incorrect because it requires an intersection between infinitely many halfspaces.

But, seemsto me like I formulated it correctly above.  Can someone please correct me?

**EDIT** $P$ is the intersection of the unit ball and the nonnegative orthant $R_+^n$.

Comment: is it possible to have $||x||_2 >1?$

Comment: Can you describe the set $P$ in simpler terms, say in the $n=2$ case?  What does it look like.  How many vertices does it have?

Comment: @kimchilover i editted that in thanks

Comment: @WillJagy I don't think so because we are restricting it.  try plugging x and y into the cauchy schwarz inequality and i think you see what I mean.

Comment: So it has a curved side, so it's convex but not a polyhedron. Your TA is right; your matrix trick can only encode finitely many half spaces.  If you follow your recipe in the case $n=2$ you will get a polygon somehow approximating $P$.

Comment: If $x$ has length more than $1,$ what multiple of $x$ has norm $1?$ Here we are using the same 2-norm.

Comment: Yes, if I take it at face value like that, then I agree with you. But somehow I am misunderstanding how formulating the problem in the matrices I showed in the equation above is incorrect...seems okay from that perspective, right?  What am I mising?

Answer (score 3):

"Then I can form matrices for all of the restrictions ..."

You then proceed to show how you can enforce the restriction
$x^Ty \leq 1$ for one particular value of $y$ such that 
$\lVert y \rVert_2 = 1.$
But there are infinitely many values of $y$ such that
$\lVert y \rVert_2 = 1.$
To form matrices for *all* of the restrictions, do you intend to form infinitely many matrices?
(Not just infinitely many, by the way; there are an *uncountable* number of solutions to $\lVert y \rVert_2 = 1.$)

The edit to the question makes this even clearer: you are aware that the unit sphere in $R^n$ provides part of the boundary of the set you are trying to delimit.
For example, for $n = 2$ you are looking at a right-angled pie-slice of the unit disk, bounded by two segments and a $\frac\pi2$-radian arc.
Intuitively, you should *know* that this is not a polygon.

---

**Postscript:** The derivation actually goes off the rails sooner than I indicated above.
The formula for a polyhedron that you are attempting to invoke is specified by *one matrix.*  A different matrix gives you a different polyhedron.
As soon as you wrote "matrices" while still trying to show that the single figure in the exercise is a polyhedron, you were no longer using that formula for a polyhedron.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.  But I did not restrict $y^Ty=1$ to anything other than the equality constraints given by the problem statement $||y||_2=1$, except that I squared both sides to get rid of the square root.  But that shouldn't be an issue.  Where exactly am I enforcing it for "one particular value of y"?

Comment: Right here: $A=[diag(-1);y^T].$ You don't have a matrix $A$ until you plug in a vector $y.$ Actually it seems to me this step is already a gross distortion of how the matrix $A$ defines a polyhedron. Look, since the figure is _obviously not a polyhedron,_ whatever made you think it was a polyhedron _must have had at least one error_ in reasoning. Perhaps you do not really understand how a matrix defines a polyhedron. I suggest you study up on that definition of a polyhedron carefully, including detailed examination of at least one example with multiple faces in the positive orthant.